# Verification on probabilities and interpretation of evaluation scores

Tags: probability, forecasting, prediction, model-evaluation, scoring-rules

my situation is the following:

I have a matrix consists of purchase probabilities for different products per user.
Retrospectively I have another matrix consists of **real-purchases**. Now my task is to verify my purchase probabilities on the new, additional information given. 

My output should be something like 'the probabilities of product 1 are overrated or underrated'.

I have tried different scores like brier-score or hit-rate BUT - and here is my problem - 
I have like 100.000 users and 100-500 purchases per product. So, just 1% of my real-purchase data covers the other probabilitiy matrix. Therefore my scores a really small and implicit "good estimations" but that is probably  wrong.

Any idea which evaluation scores are useful in this case?